# How to set the background color of WebStorm's UI?

Tags: webstorm

I just downloaded the latest WebStorm. The background color for the files is white while WebStorm's user interface (panel frames, gutter, buttons) is dark. It's a little distracting.

Is it possible to change the background-color of WebStorm's user interface to white, like it used to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavour` > `Appearance` and select a theme of your choice. I can recommend [color-themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) for additional themes.

You can also configure the colors individually at `Settings` > `Editor` > `Colors & Fonts` > `General`